# File upload in dotnet core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm trying to follow the dotnet core example here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads

with a few minor adjustments on the controller side. The following is what my form looks like:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="Test" asp-action="DoUpload">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <p>Upload one or more files using this form:</p>
        <input type="file" name="files" multiple />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Things to note: the asp-controller and asp-action is just changed to direct the form to a different controller. Additionally the name of the only input is "files". The enctype is set to "multipart/form-data".

So the corresponding controller code is simply the following:

```
public JsonResult DoUpload (List<IFormFile> files) {

        return Json(files.Count);

 }
```

So the expectation is it just returns the number of files submitted - this never seems to work. I've tried many different variations, but nothing seems to work. I tried the following:

```
//public JsonResult DoUpload([FromForm] Object obj, [FromForm] IFormFile file) { <-- Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor.
    //public async Task<IActionResult> Post(List<IFormFile> files) <- files is always empty
    //public JsonResult DoUpload(IFormFile files) { <- Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor.
    //public JsonResult DoUpload(UploadedDocument files) { <- attachment attribute, which is IFormFile is null
    //public JsonResult DoUpload ( [FromBody] UploadedDocument files) { <- 415 Unsupported Media Type
    //public JsonResult DoUpload ( [FromForm] UploadedDocument files) { <- {"attachment":null}
    //public JsonResult DoUpload (UploadedDocument file, IFormFile doc) { <- Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor.
    //public JsonResult DoUpload (List<IFormFile> files ) { <- files is null 
    //public JsonResult DoUpload (Object files) { <- returns {} when (attempting to return Json(files))
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? I'm really sorry if there is a simple fix, but I can't seem to find a solution or help anywhere else online

Comment: Did you omit the HttpPost attribute from the action or is really missing in our code ? What is the response code of the request 404, 500 ?

Comment: No you didn't. Your DoUpload method is completely different from that in the example.

Comment: @Mardoxx - I agree. I'm following the example, and as with most projects, I need the server code to deviate a bit for my specific situation. I'm sorry if I misrepresented the problem but I still can't seem to figure out what the solution might be

Comment: @vasiloreshenski I have the following decorations: [HttpPost] and 
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

Comment: @vasiloreshenski the response code in this specific scenario is 200 - where  the argument is List<IFormFile> and I'm returning Json(files.count). it prints out 0 every time regardless of the number of files I select

Comment: @user3620475 Where are you printing the result of the request ? Can you show the code ?

Comment: @vasiloreshenski sure, the controller just returns Json, so it just gets printed out in the browser after it posts. Here is a screenshot : https://imgur.com/a/MbDCn

Comment: @vasiloreshenski I'm starting to think (and hope) it's a problem with my local server configuration. Somehow. So looking into that as well

Comment: @vasiloreshenski here is my front-end code: https://pastebin.com/HqSAhJB9

Comment: @vasiloreshenski and here is my server code: https://pastebin.com/tmqSF3qS

Comment: @user3620475 I have tested both of the approaches from your code -> using the form and the js function and both worked for me .. i am confused are you sure you're selecting any files using the Browse button ?

Comment: @vasiloreshenski that's good news!! based on this I'm convinced something is wrong with my server config or maybe even my default template - I'm looking into those now. Thank you so much for your input.